# Как положить result ajax в php переменную?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Здравствуйте подскажите пожалуйста,никогда не работал с ajax js старался его обходить.Сейчас встретились лицом к лицу.Нужно было получить переменную из js в php.Нашёл совет на QS сделать запрос к другому php и получить result.

```
$.ajax ({
     url: url,
     data: { map : coords[0],
            map2 : coords[1]},
     success: function( result ) {
         alert( result );
     }
 });
```

Собственно я так и сделал,а дальше-то как? Переменные так и остаются в js так как вылезают в alert.Как быть не подскажете,что-то гугл выводит кучу информации,но не ту которую нужно.Уже не знаю как быть с этим.Задача стоит без обновления и без базы данных обновлять значение по действию на странице.По сути всё отправляется и возвращается.Но по факту переменная всё равно остаётся в js.

Comment: @Alex, в alert отображается не переменная, а результат, который вы получаете от сервера. Не хотите его получать - не выводите

Answer (score 0):

```js
function somethingFunction(){

    var variable_1 = "STRING";
    var variable_2 = 123;
    var variable_3 = {json: 'format'};

 // Формирование json для отправки
    var sendData = { variable_1: variable_1 , variable_2: variable_2, variable_3: variable_3};
    $.ajax ({
        type: 'POST', // Метод отправляемых данных (GET/POST)
        url: "/something", // путь до PHP Обработчика
        data: sendData, // Данные для отправки
        dataType: 'json', // Данные которые прийдут от обработчика, принимаемые значения (xml, json, script, or html)
        success: function(data) // Действие при успешной отправки
        {
        // Результирующие данные (data) после отправки на php обработчик, то есть что он выдаст после того как обработает данные. В формате JSON
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(err) // Действие при неудачной отправки
        {
         console.error('Ошибка отправки данных');
         //console.error('Статус ошибки: ', JSON.parse(err.responseText).status);
         //console.error('Название ошибки: ', JSON.parse(err.responseText).error);
            
            // 404 - страница не найдена.
        }
    });
}

somethingFunction();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```